# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS OVAL missing version check for vulnerability in older kernel

Tags: kernel, 22.04, security

On the NVD website, [CVE-2023-1989](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-1989) is stated as being present in various kernels, among them 5.11 to 5.15.105. After an OpenSCAP scan of a 5.15.0 image, I noticed that vulnerability and several others to be missing from the generated report.

In the [Jammy OVAL XML](https://security-metadata.canonical.com/oval/com.ubuntu.jammy.usn.oval.xml.bz2) file that OpenSCAP uses, the CVE definition exists under `oval:com.ubuntu.jammy:def:60331000000`, which specifies two tests:

```
    <unix:uname_test check="at least one" comment="Is kernel 6.1.0-\d+(-oem) currently running?" id="oval:com.ubuntu.jammy:tst:603310000000" version="1">
        <unix:object object_ref="oval:com.ubuntu.jammy:obj:603310000000"/>
        <unix:state state_ref="oval:com.ubuntu.jammy:ste:603310000000"/>
    </unix:uname_test>
    <ind:variable_test id="oval:com.ubuntu.jammy:tst:603310000010" version="1" check="all" check_existence="all_exist" comment="kernel version comparison">
        <ind:object object_ref="oval:com.ubuntu.jammy:obj:603310000010"/>
        <ind:state state_ref="oval:com.ubuntu.jammy:ste:603310000010"/>
    </ind:variable_test>
```

The `state_ref` links to:

```
    <ind:variable_state id="oval:com.ubuntu.jammy:ste:603310000010" version="1">
        <ind:value datatype="debian_evr_string" operation="less than">0:6.1.0-1009</ind:value>
    </ind:variable_state>
```

Which ends up meaning that only kernels running 6.1.0-n are checked for n<1099. However, a 5.15.0 kernel, for example, does have the vulnerability, since [its source](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-source-5.15.0) does not contain the [corresponding patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=73f7b171b7c09139eb3c6a5677c200dc1be5f318) in `drivers/bluetooth/btsdio.c`.

Why does the OVAL file not include a check for older kernels?

Comment: See https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2023-1989 for an explanation of why the Ubuntu Security Team has assigned a "low" priority to this CVE.

Comment: Questions regarding the Ubuntu OVAL data should probably be sent to the Security Team, not Ask Ubuntu.  Only the Security Team has insights into the OVAL data.  By the way, E. Baretto's answer below is the Security Team's official reply, because I forwarded this question to them ;)

Answer (score 3):

CVE-2023-1989 was not fixed yet for the source package `linux` in Jammy as you can confirm [here, on the Ubuntu Security Tracker page for CVE-2023-1989](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2023-1989).

From the OVAL snippets you can also get the USN number and confirm on its [USN announcement page](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6033-1), which only covered source package `linux-oem-6.1`.

Whenever the kernel team patches that CVE in `linux` source package on Jammy, the Ubuntu Security Team will be publishing a new USN which will then be added to the OVAL file on a new entry.

Comment: FYI, Eduardo Barretto is a member of the **Ubuntu Security Team** so this is an authoritative answer **on behalf of the Ubuntu Security Team**.  (FYI they poked me and said they'd be posting this reply and to be on the lookout for it so I can add this blurb).  And they answered because I put this on the Security team's radar.  **TL;DR, this is an authoritative answer, so if you downvote you should probably explain why.**